# Regular expression for decimal numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to form regular expression for decimal numbers.

I've tried this

`"^[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$"`

But I get false result with decimal numbers. What is wrong?

EDIT: I'm working in a application web that you put in a textbox a number and it gets translated in Italian. To identifie what kind of number is the input i use regex. When my input is 12.00002 for example  my result is false.

Comment: What do you try to do exactly? You wanna check your string is `decimal`? Have you ever look `decimal.TryParse`?

Comment: regex looks fine.How are you applying it

Comment: Your regex looks fine. You can use `\d*(\.\d)?`, if you are looking for compact regex.

Comment: "but I get false" - `bool result = Regex.IsMatch("2.2", "^[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$"); //true`

Comment: @Rawling: This should be closed with **not reproducible** or **unclear what you are asking**, not duplicate.

Comment: This works fine for me. Check out https://regex101.com/ for a pretty good online regex tester

Comment: It is clear that the regular expression is working well, but without knowing the input, we cannot help you adjust this. Maybe you are trying to check plus/minus symbols before the numbers? If yes, you have an improper regex. Anyway, [here is the page where you will find what you need](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Questions like this about regular expressions are very hard to answer without either a detailed description of what should be matched, or ample examples of what should and should not match.  Especially when you say it doesn't work.  What does it not work for?

Comment: Please post the code you have, otherwise, this question must be closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

This should work for you.
Better  would be to Use compact one:

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Usage for Two digits and two decimal points:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Decimal Number.")]
```

Comment: Why would you think the OP only wants to match 2 decimal places?

Comment: That can be modified accordingly.